# how could it works if function is called before it is defined in python?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I was wondering what does `if __name__ == "__main__":` really do in python, I have the following code in python3:

```
def main():
    test();

def test():
    print("hello world " + __name__);

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main();
```

we know that we have to declare a function before we use it, so function call inside of `if` part works fine, the `main()` is defined before it is called inside of `if` statement, but what about the test() function, it is defined after it is called and there is no errors:

```
def main():
    test();

def test():
    print("hello world " + __name__);
```

so how could it works if the `test()` function is defined after it is called?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do?rq=1

Comment: I read that link, but it does not answer my question, so I ask a new question

Comment: You chose a bad title for your question, which causes it to be closed. I think your question is valid, but judging by the title alone, it is not (for being a duplicate)...

Comment: You have two separate questions here. Your first one—the one in your title—is very definitely answered by that question. The second one—how `test` works—is not. And that's why you should write each separate question as a separate question: so each one can be answered or usefully closed, instead of all but the first one being ignored by most of the community.

Comment: Well, `test()` is under the function `main()` & `main()` DOES NOT get executed until it is called. Thus, if you declare `test()` after calling `main()` then it will give you `NameError`. But, if you define `test()` before calling `main()` (in which `test()` is called), the code will work.

Comment: @user2131316 I'm voting to reopen, the issue is that you've misidentified what the problem is.  Your question has nothing to do with `if __name__ == "__main__":` and everything to do with what the python interpreter does when it compiles functions.

Comment: @user2131316: If you edit this question to be about your second question instead of the duplicate first question, I'm pretty sure it will get reopened.

Comment: Changed the title, and voting to reopen.

Comment: I changed the question title and voted to reopen, what else can I do?

Comment: Voila! It is reopened.

Comment: "*we know that we have to declare a function before we use it*" - Whoever taught you that, lied.

Comment: Wow. How do you mark 2 duplicates!? :P

Comment: @Robᵩ: Well, you do have to _define_ a function before you use it. (There's really no such thing as "declaring" in Python—that whole declare/define distinction only makes sense in languages like C-style variables-as-typed-memory-locations…) The reason it works is that he _is_ defining the function before he uses it.

Comment: @abarnert - precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we know that we have to declare a function before we use it

It sounds like you're coming from a language in the C family. These languages are different in two ways.

First, Python doesn't "declare" anything. That makes sense in languages like C, where variables are typed memory locations that values get stored in. But in Python, values have their own independent types and locations, and variables are just names for those values, so there is nothing to declare.

Now, Python requires you to *define* a function before you *use* it, just like C.

But only C *also* requires you to define, or at least declare, a function before you compile a function whose body uses it. The difference is the same as above—C needs the function to be declared, to get the types, the pointer to the function's actual code, etc.; in Python, the function is just a name for the function-object value. To compile a function, all it needs to know is where to look up the names. And that's easy: it compiles the function so that, at runtime, it will look up the name in the module globals. Since no other information is needed, there's nothing to declare.

For example, in C, this is legal:

```
void foo() {}
void bar() { foo(); }
```

And so is this:

```
void foo();
void bar() { foo(); }
void foo() {}
```

But this is not:

```
void bar() { foo(); }
void foo();
```

In Python, because there are no declarations, the second and third are identical, and therefore both perfectly valid:

```
def bar():
    foo()
def foo():
    pass
```

Answer (score 5):

Test is **not** defined after it is called. The order is:

1. Define `main`. This references a (yet undefined) `test`, but does not actually use (call) it. Python is ok with that.
2. Define `test`.
3. Call `main`.
4. `main` calls `test`. No problem, as it is already defined.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here really has nothing to do with `if __name__ == 'main'`.  Consider the following code:

```
def do_something():
    do_something_else()
```

The above is a valid function declaration.  *Even if* I haven't written `do_something_else()` yet.  Feel free to try this out in your interactive interpreter.  Now, when I actually **call** `do_something()`:

```
do_something()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-3d57cd7a951b> in <module>()
----> 1 do_something()

<ipython-input-20-5d71722aad44> in do_something()
      1 def do_something():
----> 2     do_something_else()
      3 

NameError: global name 'do_something_else' is not defined
```

It errors out.  It would not if, at some point at any time before invoking `do_something()`, I had defined my `do_something_else` function.

So, what does this mean?  Python does indeed interpret top-to-bottom.  But when a function definition is reached, it merely **compiles** the function, it does not execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Python executes code in the order it sees it.

You type in `def main():` it takes it as a function definition to be run later.

The `if __name__ == "__main__":` checks if the current file is the one that is supposed to be run (as opposed to included). and in that case it will execute whatver is below (usually `main`)

You can put something like this:

```
print "here"
def main():
  print "in main"

if __name__ == "__main__"
  main()
```

and you should see an output like

```
here
in main
```

This is because python is intrinsically a scripting language and functions are optional.
That being said for any piece of code that's not meant to be thrown away in the next 10 minutes you should use functions and classes. They make the code easier to understand follow and debug.

The reason your particular code works (with test defined after main) is that you run it after everything is defined. Python will not attempt to check if there's a `test` to be called unless you run main. When you run `main`, `test` has already been defined.